# How to create async action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, autodesk-forge, cloudflare

I have a page that needs parameters received by a request from a third-party service. Unfortunately, the request takes a long time and the server crashes with a 504 error.

```
def show
  start_time = Time.now
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  file = File.new(project.rvt_schema, 'rb')
  rvt_params = ForgeHandler.instance.get_urn_token_params(file, "#{@project.id.to_s}.rvt")
  @urn = rvt_params[:urn]
  @token = rvt_params[:token]
  end_time = Time.now
end
```

The most time inside the method is taken by request:

```
  # Translate previously uploaded file to SVF format
  def translate_to_svf(object_id,access_token)
    base_64_urn = Base64.strict_encode64(object_id)
    response = RestClient.post("#{API_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job",
                               {
                                   input: {
                                       urn: base_64_urn
                                   },
                                   output: {
                                       formats: [
                                           {
                                               type: "svf",
                                               views: [
                                                   "3d"
                                               ]
                                           }
                                       ]
                                   }
                               }.to_json,
                               { Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}", content_type:'application/json' })
    return response
  end
```

Which status is checked in cycle by another method:

```
def verify_job_complete(base_64_urn,access_token)
    is_complete = false
    while(!is_complete)
      response = RestClient.get("#{API_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/#{base_64_urn}/manifest",
                                { Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}"} )
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      if(json["progress"]=="complete")
        is_complete = true
        puts("***** Finished translating your file to SVF - status: #{json['status']}, progress: #{json['progress']} ")
      else
        puts("***** Haven't finished translating your file to SVF - status: #{json['status']}, progress: #{json['progress']} ")
        sleep 5
      end
    end
```

I would like to implement asynchronous parameter loading. So I want to load data  after losing control of the controller but but initializing the beginning of data loading from remote request in it. Tell me how best to implement this.
Or another way that would remove the error "Gateway timeout".

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to offload asynchronous stuff to a [worker](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and save a reference to the user that needs to know about it. If you couple it with something like [StimulusReflex](https://docs.stimulusreflex.com/) you can render the result once it's finished. Another option might be the [Render Async](https://github.com/renderedtext/render_async) gem.

Answer (score -2):

While this might be more of a question for the `ruby-on-rails` community, let me answer from the Autodesk Forge standpoint:

First of all, you should never wait for the Model Derivative job to complete when handling a request to your server. If the design file is complex enough, the translation could take up to hours, so this should definitely be handled asynchronously.

One option is to poll the status of the translation by requesting "derivative manifest" using the [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) endpoint.

Another option is to setup a [Forge Webhook](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/overview) to get notified when the [extraction.finished](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.finished) event is triggered.